# iOS delegate crash

Tags: ios, delegates, crash

In my app I am implementing lazy loading with a class I call ThumbDownloader

To start an image download, my UITableView cellForRowAtIndexPath method calls this method:

```
- (void)startIconDownload:(Product *)product forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ThumbDownloader *thumbDownloader = [imageDownloadsInProgress objectForKey:indexPath];
    if (thumbDownloader == nil) 
    {
        thumbDownloader = [[ThumbDownloader alloc] init];
        thumbDownloader.product = product;
        thumbDownloader.imageSizeWidth = 87;
        thumbDownloader.imageSizeHeight = 87;
        thumbDownloader.indexPathInTableView = indexPath;
        thumbDownloader.delegate = self;
        [imageDownloadsInProgress setObject:thumbDownloader forKey:indexPath];
        [thumbDownloader startDownload];
        [thumbDownloader release];   
    }
}
```

The thumbdownloader class, when finished downloading the image, calls a method in my main class (listingView) called:

```
- (void)appImageDidLoad:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

The problem is, if I enter listingView and quickly leave while the images are downloading, the app crashes with:

```
-[listingView appImageDidLoad:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x3beed10
```

Here is my dealloc

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [myTable release], myTable = nil;
    [imageDownloadsInProgress release], imageDownloadsInProgress = nil;
    [spinView release], spinView = nil; 
    [mainView release], mainView = nil;
    [tableView release], tableView = nil;

    [myVs release], myVs = nil;
    [filteredVs release], filteredVs = nil;
    [toolBar release], toolBar = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}
```

I have tried to iterate through the Thumbdownloader instances within imageDownloadsInProgress to set their delegates to nil, but when I try that it crashes as well...like this:

```
- (void)dealloc
{

    for(ThumbDownloader *thumbDownloader in imageDownloadsInProgress)
        if(thumbDownloader !=nil && thumbDownloader.delegate!=nil)
            thumbDownloader.delegate = nil;

    .....
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use that code for set image to UIImageView, you should try to use `"UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"` category from AFNetworking framework for this issue. You need just set `[image setImageWithUrl:@"http://myImage"];`

Comment: sorry, this does not help me.  I need to know, with using my existing code, how to set the delegate to nil so it doesnt crash